# Manually altering history inside a vue.js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm working on a vue.js v3 project, with vue-router.

Routing is fine, not an issue. But I have a sliding panel to display some informations. This sliding panel can be called from different views/routes. And I want to keep the view state (scroll, etc...) when I'm displaying the sliding panel.

For that, this sliding panel is on my App.vue file

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
  <SlidingPanel v-if="post"/>
</template>
```

`post` is stored in a store : when you click on a post, this post object is stored on a store, and the sliding panel is opened.

**This works fine**

But the natural behavior is to slide back (from the right side of your phone) to close the panel. I did a trick to do so

```
router.beforeEach((to,from) => {
  if(store.state.post.post) {
    store.commit('post/hide')
    return false;
  }
}
```

which means : if you're going back into history with the sliding panel opened, it will cancel your "go back", and close the panel instead.

**This works fine**

But if it's the first time you're visiting the webapp, opening the sliding panel, your "go back" gesture will go back your browsing history, and you will leave the website. That's not what I want.

On of my idea will be to add an history element if the `from` property inside the `router.beforeEach()` function is empty, and do so every time you open the sliding panel. Do you think it's a good idea or do you have any recommendation doing something else ?
And I'm struggling adding an element inside my router.history. I tried `router.push()`or `window.history.state` but it's not working as expected (it's not inside the vue.js history). Do you have an idea ?

Comment: I think I found a trick : using hash on the url to add artificial history, and play along this hash to open/close my panel. Then, every panel opening is adding a seamless hash in the url, which create a browser history. Not that nice, but working... If you have a better idea, I would like to read it :-)

Comment: Not sure how it's supposed to work exactly, probably checking for the initial navigation could help, in case you need to handle it differently, https://router.vuejs.org/api/#START-LOCATION

Comment: Instead of hash maybe try adding a query parameter to the URL, to add it to the history that way. ie. `router.push({ name: 'post', query: { panel: 'open' }})`, you could then assign it 'open' or 'closed' and add a route guard to handle back clicks accordingly based on the panel status

Comment: Thank you @paddyfields. Your solution is a bit nicer than mine, but it's kind of the same thing.

Comment: @Estus, START-LOCATION seems to always return the first location of the app, not really what I wanted. But thank you for your help both of us !

Comment: @Pof, no problem. Same concept for sure, just a little more intuitive for the next dev who comes along in your codebase and deletes the hash thinking it isn't needed :)